# Div class not showing on dropdown select?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Good day

I require some aid with this issue.

I have a "Location1" dropdown with about 10 options. I then have a div class I would like to show if the user selects "Other".

Code:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#Location1").on('change' function(){
 if (this.value == 'Other') {
 $(".otherlocation1").show();
}
else {
$(".otherlocation1").hide();
}
});
});
</script>
```

It's supposed to hide div class "otherlocation1" on by default, and then show "otherlocation1" based on a selection from the "Location1" text box.

Only problem is, it's not working. I've tried numerous other ways and can't get it working.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are missing a `,` after `change`. Try this:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
   $("#Location1").on('change', function() {
     if (this.value == 'Other') {
       $(".otherlocation1").show();
     } else {
       $(".otherlocation1").hide();
     }
   });
 });
```

```css
.otherlocation1{
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id='Location1'>
  <option disabled selected>Select an option</option>
  <option value='Other'>Other</option>
  <option value='Other 2'>Other 2</option>
  <option value='Other 3'>Other 3</option>
  <option value='Other 4'>Other 4</option>
  <option value='Other 5'>Other 5</option>
</select>
<p class='otherlocation1'>otherlocation1</p>
```

Comment: Oh my word! Can't believe I missed the ",". Thanks a lot man this worked.

Answer (score 1):

In Jquery the `on` function takes two parameters.

- events
- handler

So when you call the `on` function you pass the event and the handler separated by a comma ',' . Refer [this](http://api.jquery.com/on/) for more info.

Thus refactor your line as follows

```
 $("#Location1").on('change', function()
```

Comment: Thank you. I missed the comma! Was a long day of work and I just couldn't figure out what was wrong. Guess I was a bit burned out with all the other stuff I wrote.